# Java multi-dimensional array unable to add values dynamically

Tags: java, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array something like this:

```
String[][] A = {{"a","b","c","d"}};
```

and I need to append values to this arraysome thing like this

```
while(rs.next()){
A.add(rs.getString(1)); -->e
A.add(rs.getString(1)); -->f
A.add(rs.getString(1)); -->g
A.add(rs.getString(1)); -->h
}
```

I need the resultant array like this:

```
Sting[][] A = {{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}}
```

Also we can not predict the while(...) which may contain multiple values like

```
Sting[][] A = {{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"},{"A","B","C","D"},......}
```

I know `A.add` won't work here. How can I make this possible dynamically? Please help me

Comment: use ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> instead if String[][]... it allows for your unpredictability of data size since otherwise arrays have to have fixed size...

Comment: FWIW, there are plenty of libraries out there to read from ResultSet into Collections. Also takes care of opening and closing them properly, transforming rows into beans and other useful boilerplate. Many lightweight (not the whole ORM overhead). I like Commons DbUtils and jooQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, since the size of the array is fixed, and it's determined when you first initialize it to be 1 row with 4 columns.
If you need an array like structure with a dynamic length, use an `ArrayList`.

If the internal array has a fixed length (it seems to be 4 in your example), you can use an ArrayList that contains arrays :

```
List<String[]> A = new ArrayList<String[]>();

// repeat this as many times as you need
String[] arr = new String[4];
arr[0]=...
arr[1]=...
arr[2]=...
arr[3]=...
A.add(arr);
```

If the number of columns is not constant, use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

Here's one way to convert the List to array after you finish populating it:

```
String[][] array = new String[A.size()][4];
int i=0;
for (String[] arr : A) {
    array[i] = arr;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @androidGenX I just did.

Comment: I am passing to afunction to drawtable; public static void drawTable(PDPage page, PDPageContentStream contentStream, float y, float margin, String[][] content). where content is what you told me to put as list. So it will create error!!

Comment: If you need `String[][]` at the end of the day, you'll have to convert it back. Or figure out the size upfront. But you cannot resize Java arrays.

Comment: @androidGenX Is `drawTable` a method you have no control over? If that's the case, you have to convert the List to String[][] before passing it to this method. After you put all the values in the List, you know what size you need, and you can create an array `new String[A.size()][4]` that can holds all your data.

Comment: How can make that array which can convert List to array. Can you write it down?? @Eran help me buddy!

Comment: @Eran Incompatible type : Object can not be converted to String. ERRor. In this line for (String[] arr : A) {

Comment: @androidGenX My bad. I forgot to declare `A` to be generic - should be `List<String[]> A`. Fixed now.

Comment: @Eran buddy you are simply awsome!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

To set up a multi-dimensional `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

This creates an `ArrayList` with no rows.

To add a row, I'd create the row as a separate variable:

```
ArrayList<String> newRow = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

and then add it to the two-dimensional array like:

```
a.add(newRow);
```

You could do this in one statement, but it starts looking a little messy.

To add to an existing row--suppose you want to add a string to the end of the 2nd row, which has index 1:

```
a.get(1).add("d");
```

`get` will return the `ArrayList<String>` at position 1; this returns a *reference*, so you can modify the row.

Comment: If you code to the interface, you can do `List<String> newRow = Arrays.asList("a", "b");` directly. Even `a.add(asList("a", "b"))` does not look that messy, then.

Comment: @Thilo You can't do that with `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`; the last `asList` won't return an `ArrayList`.  You could make it `ArrayList<List<String>>`, but you may lose some `ArrayList`-specific functionality.  It depends on what you'll need to do with the two-dimensional array.

Comment: I agree that `a.get(1).add("d")` may not work anymore. You can use a copying constructor then.